# Issue using 802.11ac at gigabit speeds and WMM on Macbook Pro

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

The router is a Netgear r6250 (ac1600). When I enable the WMM (Wireless Multimedia) setting, which allows the full bandwidth of ac, and the computer is for instance streaming online video, or video over ip within a browser like a chatroom, I am unable to open another page on the same computer. The browser is academic, including if I try to use a different browser for each. The source of the video does not influence the performance either. I will try to resolve another webpage, which this page doesn't matter except that smaller pages are more likely to go through, but not by much. Sometimes trying over and over again will yield a result, other times not. I have played with the QoS settings to no avail, and turning off the WMM uses the 802.11a standard only and connects at 54 Mbps. Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

My wifi scans read the width as such: 20 MHz for 5 GHz and 20 MHz for 2.4 GHz with WMM disabled, and 80 MHz for 5GHz and 40 MHz for 2.4 GHz. This problem only occurs on my MacbookPro 11,3 15 in Retina, as it is the only computer on my network that uses 802.11ac, and while it is happening on my MBP I can load a webpage on my iPhone, or another computer just fine.

Comment: You kind of forgot to describe the problem. You say "I am unable to open another page on the same computer", but don't explain why or what happens when you try.

Comment: I don't understand the problem beyond that it won't load any webpages, whilst streaming...could you please say ask me something to help you get the information you need to better understand my question? Which there was in fact a question: Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: here is an example: If I am streaming netflix and I open another tab and type google.com into the address bar and hit enter, the page never loads. If I close the browser and wait 5 seconds, I can go to google and the page loads, but if I reopen netflix the same problem occurs. why? and how do I fix it? (the streaming site doesn't have to be netflix nor does the other site have to be google)

Comment: Is the netgear firmware version 1.0.1.84?  if not update...

Comment: It is 1.0.1.84, is there a possibility that going wit an open source os will fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching my router's OS to DD-WRT K3, and it completely fixed my problem. I sent a continuous ping of 4,000 packets to my router and had 0% loss, which is a huge difference from the 60% - 98% packet loss I was getting before I changed the OS.